# Multiple graphs have problem when use annotate

Tags: ggplot2, annotate, geom

I have a data set (generated as below) and made 3 graphs G1, G2, G3 (codes are below). When I print a graph after creating it there is no problem. However, If I print them after all of them created, only the last graphs is ok but the first 2 have problem.

I am trying to find what is going wrong. Any comment is deeply appreciated.

Kind Regards

Seyit Ali KAYIS
seyitali.kayis@ibu.edu.tr

codes

#################################################

```
library(tidyverse)

set.seed <-10

Var1 <- rnorm (90, 25, 3)
Var2 <- rnorm (90, 15, 3)
Var3 <- rnorm (90, 5, 1)
Gr   <- c(rep("C", 15), rep("T", 15), rep("C", 15), rep("T", 15), rep("C", 15), rep("T", 15) )  
Time <- c(rep(1, 30), rep(2, 30), rep(3, 30) )   

MyData <- data.frame(Var1, Var2, Var3, Gr, Time)

MyData <- within(MyData, {
   Gr <- factor( Gr ) 
   Time <- factor( Time ) 
    
 }
  )

str(MyData)

name2 <- names(MyData)  


####################     Graphs    ##################################

 Tsize <- 30

 My_Theme1 = theme_classic()+
 theme(
 panel.border=element_rect(color = "black", fill=NA, size=2),
 axis.line=element_line(size=0.5, color="black"),
 axis.ticks=element_line(size=1.5, color="black"),
 axis.title.x = element_text(size = Tsize, color = "black"),
 axis.text.x = element_text(size = Tsize, color = "black"), 
 axis.title.y = element_text(size = Tsize, color = "black"),
 axis.text.y = element_text(size = Tsize, color = "black"),
 plot.title = element_text(size = Tsize, hjust=0.5, color = "black"),
legend.title =  element_text(size = Tsize, color = "black"),
legend.text =   element_text(size = Tsize, color = "black"),
strip.background = element_rect(colour= "black", fill=NA), 
panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "white")   ) 


################    Graph Var1  ##########################################
i<- 1

xcoor1 = c(0.8, 1.8, 2.8, 1.2, 2.2, 3.2)
ycoor1 =  c(40, 40, 40, 37, 37, 37)
letters1 = c("a", "b", "c", "A", "A", "B")

G1 <-  ggplot(data = MyData, mapping = aes(x = Time  , y = MyData[,i], fill=Gr)) +  
      stat_boxplot(geom = "errorbar", width = 0.4, lwd=1.5, position = position_dodge(width = 0.75) ) +  
      geom_boxplot(lwd=1.5) +    
      ggtitle("A" ) +  xlab("Time")  +   ylab(paste(name2[i])) +  
      annotate(geom="text", x=xcoor1, y=ycoor1, label=letters1, size=10 ) + 
      My_Theme1
      
print(G1) # No problem
     
################    Graph Var2  ##########################################
     
 i<- 2

xcoor2 = c(0.8, 1.8, 2.8, 1.2, 2.2, 3.2)
ycoor2 =  c(28, 28, 28, 25, 25, 25)
letters2 = c("a", "b", "c", "A", "A", "B")

G2 <-  ggplot(data = MyData, mapping = aes(x = Time  , y = MyData[,i], fill=Gr)) +  
     stat_boxplot(geom = "errorbar", width = 0.4, lwd=1.5, position = position_dodge(width = 0.75) ) +  
     geom_boxplot(lwd=1.5) +    
      ggtitle("B" ) +  xlab("Time")  +   ylab(paste(name2[i])) +  
      annotate(geom="text", x=xcoor2, y=ycoor2, label=letters2, size=10 ) + 
      My_Theme1

print(G2) # No problem
      
################    Graph Var3  ##########################################
   
 i<- 3

xcoor3 = c(0.8, 1.8, 2.8, 1.2, 2.2, 3.2)
ycoor3 =  c(10, 10, 10, 8.5, 8.5, 8.5)
letters3 = c("a", "b", "c", "A", "A", "B")

G3 <-  ggplot(data = MyData, mapping = aes(x = Time  , y = MyData[,i], fill=Gr)) +  
      stat_boxplot(geom = "errorbar", width = 0.4, lwd=1.5, position = position_dodge(width = 0.75) ) +  
      geom_boxplot(lwd=1.5) +    
      ggtitle("C" ) +  xlab("Time")  +   ylab(paste(name2[i])) +  
      annotate(geom="text", x=xcoor3, y=ycoor3, label=letters3, size=10 ) + 
      My_Theme1

print(G3) # No problem         
        
print(G1) # PROBLEM: GRAPH CHANGED
print(G2) # PROBLEM: GRAPH CHANGED
print(G3) # No problem
```

If I remove the lines
"annotate(geom="text", x=xcoor1, y=ycoor1, label=letters1, size=10 ) +" "annotate(geom="text", x=xcoor2, y=ycoor2, label=letters2, size=10 ) +" "annotate(geom="text", x=xcoor3, y=ycoor3, label=letters3, size=10 ) +"  it is ok. But I need that lines

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, the problem comes when calling `y = MyData[,i]` in the three `aes` calls. `ggplot` doesn't look up the data until you call `print`, so when it looks up the third time, all three graphs are reading `i = 3` and plotting the same data. Change them to `y = Var1` etc. and you'll see the difference.

A solution is not to use global variables. If you're looking for a simple way of iterating over a series of values to get graphs, then you can use mapping (or `lapply` or similar if you're unfamiliar with the `purrr` parts) and create all your graphs, here outputting as objects together in a list:

```r
xcoor1 = c(0.8, 1.8, 2.8, 1.2, 2.2, 3.2)
ycoor1 =  c(40, 40, 40, 37, 37, 37)
letters1 = c("a", "b", "c", "A", "A", "B")

xcoor2 = c(0.8, 1.8, 2.8, 1.2, 2.2, 3.2)
ycoor2 =  c(28, 28, 28, 25, 25, 25)
letters2 = c("a", "b", "c", "A", "A", "B")

xcoor3 = c(0.8, 1.8, 2.8, 1.2, 2.2, 3.2)
ycoor3 =  c(10, 10, 10, 8.5, 8.5, 8.5)
letters3 = c("a", "b", "c", "A", "A", "B")

Gs <- list(
  i = 1:3,
  xcoor = list(xcoor1, xcoor2, xcoor3),
  ycoor = list(ycoor1, ycoor2, ycoor3),
  letters = list(letters1, letters2, letters3)
) |>
  pmap(function(i, xcoor, ycoor, letters) {

    # This is your ggplot code you've used above, but this time
    # it loops over each combo of data+coords+labels

    ggplot(data = MyData,
           mapping = aes(x = Time  , y = MyData[, i], fill = Gr)) +
      stat_boxplot(
        geom = "errorbar",
        width = 0.4,
        lwd = 1.5,
        position = position_dodge(width = 0.75)
      ) +
      geom_boxplot(lwd = 1.5) +
      ggtitle("C") +  xlab("Time")  +   ylab(paste(name2[i])) +
      annotate(
        geom = "text",
        x = xcoor,
        y = ycoor,
        label = letters,
        size = 10
      ) +
      My_Theme1
  })

print(Gs)
```

[image]

[image]

[image]